# C# Create a Mapping Instead of Switch Case

Tags: c#-4.0, c#-3.0, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

I am reading a csv file exported from another system and creating a record in microsoft dynamics crm using C#. However the status is different between the 2 systems so i have to read the statuses from csv and map it to the status in dynamics and use the new while creating the record

What is the best way to achieve this instead of the below switch -

```
  public string MapDEStatusToDynamics(string name) //name is from csv file
    {
        var primaryStatus=string.Empty;
        switch (name)
        {
            case "Applying for Probate": 
                primaryStatus = "Applying";
                break;

            case "Hold Up (Lending/Securities)":
                primaryStatus = "Unresolved Lending / Securities";
                break;

            case "Awaiting POD":
                primaryStatus = "Awaiting proof of death";
                break;

            case "Close Case":
                primaryStatus = "Closed";
                break;
        }
        return primaryStatus ; //primary status is text in dynamics
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is wrong with current approach?

Comment: @llya Bursov I have shown only four cases here whereas in real they are more than 10 cases which makes the code look big.

Comment: so you want shorter code, then you can return inside `case`, like `public string MapDEStatusToDynamics(string name) { switch(name) { case "some": return "another"; case "some2": return "another2";}}`

Comment: What about creating a Dictionary with all the status Keys(e.g value from 'other system') and values(value from crm) somewhere in a separate 'Helper' class?

Comment: @magicalKhachapuri thank you for responding i did the same.